# If $|a-b| \leq C$ and $|x-y|\leq D$, is there a way to bound $\left|\frac{a}{x} - \frac{b}{y}\right|$?

Tags: inequality

If $|a-b| \leq C$ and $|x-y|\leq D$, is there a nice way to bound $\left|\frac{a}{x} - \frac{b}{y}\right|$?

I made an attempt using Triangle inequality but to no avail.

\begin{align*}\left|\frac{a}{x} - \frac{b}{y}\right| &= \left|\frac{a}{x} - \frac{b}{x} + \frac{b}{x} - \frac{b}{y}\right| \\
&\leq \frac{|a-b|}{|x|} + |b| \left|\frac{y - x}{xy}\right| \\
&\leq \frac{C}{|x|} + \frac{|b|D}{|xy|}
\end{align*}
Is there a nicer one?

Comment: and the variables in the denominator?

Comment: just take $x, y$ from $(-c,c)$ for some $c $ and $a,b$ close to $1$ in order to that this cannot be true.

Comment: @Thomas, could you elaborate?

Comment: Sorry, I was referring to the subject only. If you allow $1/x$ or $1/y$ in the denominator of the bound then my statement is incorrect (but if $x=0$ or $y=0$ this is not a bound at all).

Comment: If $0\in [x-D,x+D]$, then $y$ could be 0 and $b/y$ is unbounded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about this intuitively.  Consider $|\frac{a}{x} - \frac{b}{y}|$.  Let's just keep $a$ and $b$ fixed for now.  Consider $|x - y| \leq D$, which basically means $-D \leq x-y \leq D$.  If we choose $x$ and $y$ from $(-\frac{D}{2}, \frac{D}{2})$, then we will always have $x-y$ in $(-D,D)$ (why?).

Okay, but let's fix $y$ for a moment.  We can choose $x$ as close to $0$ as we want.  That will make $|\frac{a}{x} - \frac{b}{y}|$ grow unboundedly toward $\infty$ as $x$ gets closer and closer to $0$.  So, we've seen that under all of your assumptions, we can find an example where $|\frac{a}{x} - \frac{b}{y}|$ is actually an unbounded expression.

Comment: Thanks! On a second thought, it seems that I can assume $x,y$ strictly positive.

Comment: @oeda Even with that assumption, you still have unboundedness.  Just take $x,y$ in the interval $(0,1)$.  Then they are strictly positive and $|x-y| \leq 1$, but if $y$ is fixed, $x$ can be taken as close as you want to $0$, which will make the first term go off to $\infty$.